# Plugin to show enclosing indentation levels

Tags: indentation, quickfix

I'm looking for functionality which may or may not exist. Basically, I'd like to have a location list split at the *top* of each writable buffer which shows the last line of each enclosing indentation level. So for the code:

```
def some_function(x, y, z):
    some code
    some more code
    even more code
    if var == 3:
        do something
        do another_thi|g
```

If my cursor were at `|`, I would see in this window something like

```
> def some_function(x, y, z):
>    ...
>    if var == 3
```

If this doesn't exist, could such a plugin even be made for Vim (bear with me; I'm not a real programmer)? It seems like it would be very useful for orienting oneself in one's code after e.g., coming back from the coffee pot.

Comment: Are you looking for `:help folds` ?

Comment: I'm aware of folds, and I use them, however I think what I'm thinking of is a little different (though I hadn't thought of them in this context when I posed the question). I'd like a separate window that automatically shows enclosing folds as I move my cursor about.

Comment: I guess i just dont see why not use `set foldmethod=indent`—are you looking for more of a “code outline” ? Can you [edit] to clarify how folds don’t satisfy your need and explain more clearly what you desire?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I’m guessing the OP is looking for more context to say “this is how execution ends up in this block of code”. I think `fdm=indent` differs fundamentally from what they describe  because I think in that, if the inner fold is open then the outer ones must be too? (Correct me if I’m wrong: I’m not at a computer right now.)

Comment: ...glossing over the “separate window” requirement for now.

Comment: mnosefish: it’s definitely possible, it’s not difficult, but a polished solution isn’t trivial either. I’m not aware of any existing plugins or really any that are even similar.

Comment: Yes! I'll update the question later when I'm at a box, but I'm looking for more context in a long-running function, etc. at a glance of what I guess I'll call a "context window". I suspected it might not exist, and am open to developing it myself, but I know very little about vimscript and wanted to gauge how much of an undertaking it would be

Comment: One question: I see the quickfix tag. Is “local list” in the second sentence meant to be “location list”?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's not exactly a preview window as you described but Vista.vim allows you to get the name of the [nearest function in your statusline](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vista.vim#show-the-nearest-methodfunction-in-the-statusline) and coc.nvim allows to do [the same](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Statusline-integration#current-function-symbol) maybe before developing your own plugin it could be worth it to look at them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was intending to write an answer explaining how you might go about doing this, but when I embarked on doing so I ended up with a prototype implementation instead. Writing code is often more fun than writing documentation, I'm afraid!

```
function! ShowContext() abort
  let items = []
  let l = line('.')
  let indent = 1000
  while l >= 0
    if indent(l) < indent
      call add(items, getline(l))
      let indent = indent(l)
      if indent == 0
        break
      endif
    endif
    let l -= 1
  endwhile
  lgetexpr reverse(items)
  above lopen
  wincmd p
endfunction

augroup ContextList
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorHold * call ShowContext()
augroup END
```

There are a lot of rough edges you'll need to file off, but hopefully this shows that your goal is certainly attainable. Let me know in the comments if there's anything in particular you don't understand or struggle with improving, and I'll be happy to explain more.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that as soon as I get a moment!

Comment: I just got around to trying this and it is exactly what I needed! Is there a way to toggle the autocommand on and off? I have `<leader>lo` set to toggle the location list, but this doesn't seem to work, probably because the location list is being opened from within the function.

Comment: Simplest fix is to just remove the line `above lopen` from the function, but then it's still updating the location list: just not opening it. Cleanest way to toggle the autocommand is to remove it entirely with `autocmd! ContextList` and then recreate it when you need it with the code already in the answer.

Comment: I have a bead on getting a toggle to work. Also, it's doing a thing where it resets the cursor to the beginning of the line when the autocommand fires. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The cursor movement is because I mistakenly used `lexpr` at the end of the function. It should be `lgetexpr`.

Comment: Btw, you'll need to remove the `wincmd p` line too!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Rich's](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) answer, here is my ready-to-roll solution with keymap and ignoring blank lines.

```
function! ShowContext() abort
  let items = []
  let l = line('.')
  let indent = 1000
  while l >= 0
    " added test to ignore blank lines
    if indent(l) < indent && getline(l) != ''
      call add(items, getline(l))
      let indent = indent(l)
      if indent == 0
        break
      endif
    endif
    let l -= 1
  endwhile
  lgetexpr reverse(items)
endfunction

let w:contextlist_open = 0
function! Toggle_contextlist()
    if w:contextlist_open == 1
        let w:contextlist_open = 0
        autocmd! ContextList
        above lclose
    else
        let w:contextlist_open = 1
        augroup ContextList
            autocmd!
            autocmd CursorHold * call ShowContext()
        augroup END
        above lopen
        wincmd p
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>lc :call Toggle_contextlist()<CR>

autocmd BufWinEnter * let w:locallist_open = 0
autocmd BufWinEnter * let w:contextlist_open = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Christian Wellenbrock (the author of the well regarded [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)) recently released a plugin that does this, called [context.vim](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim):

[image: blah]

It might be a good idea to try this out if you're looking for a more robust alternative to [my answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20089/343).